# Changing background on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I already have a background image set on `a:hover` and I need to OVERRIDE that image with yet another on mouseover (its based on a condition though).

I tried this, but its not working:

```
$("a").mouseover( function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/new2.png');
});
```

... it still shows the one applied to `a:hover` using CSS.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this 'not working'? Because it really should, I think.

Comment: you missed a closing bracket for url

Comment: $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/new2.png)'); will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a closing bracket for your url

Comment: That was it! Man, I shouldn't work so late, so many darn silly mistakes happening!

Answer (score 0):

extending @sahbeewah answer, close the bracket for your url

```
$("a").mouseover( function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/new2.png)');
});
```

You can also use css

```
a:hover{
   background-image : url(../images/new2.png);
}
```